# create a simple html sidebar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

All I look for is a simple sidebar for a simple website. Google results have everything about sidebar except for creating a simple side bar with minimal codes. They are so confusing, Still I have no idea about how to create a side bar. Should I use `aside` tag or using `div`? There is no clear explanation. One might help me telling what way they usually use.

My default CSS is twitter bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using Bootstrap, you could just use the container-fluid class, which should generate two columns for you - the leftmost one a sidebar. Just add some additional CSS to add a border on that column and you'll have your sidebar in at most 4 lines of CSS code.

See "Fluid Layout" here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts

Answer (score 1):

you could check this link for more info http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/115-dont-overthink-it-grids/

depending of what the content is on your sidebar you could use  if the content within the sidebar is related to the content in general the aside is a good option. If it is not the you could just add a new div and style it. Another option is to use  if the aside doesn't quite fit the bill.